# Showing different bottom navigation bars depending on role of user in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get 2 different bottom navigation bars in Flutter.
What navigation bar needs to be shown depends on the role of the user. I already got the part covered where I get the role of the user.

The error I'm getting from Flutter is: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<BottomNavigationBarItem>'`

I already tried showing more than 2 buttons in the BottomNavigationBar in the 'else' statement in showButtons() method but that wouldn't fix the problem.

This is the code I'm running at the moment:

```
class SkoolWorkshopApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SkoolWorkshopApp({Key? key, required this.rol}) : super(key: key);
  final String rol;

  @override
  _SkoolWorkshopAppState createState() => _SkoolWorkshopAppState();
}

class _SkoolWorkshopAppState extends State<SkoolWorkshopApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final TeacherScreens = [
    HomePage(),
    awaitingProfile(),
    awaitingProfile(),
    NotificationPage(),
    singleProfilePage(),
  ];

  final EmployeeScreens = [
    HomePage(),
    NotificationPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];

  final TeacherButtons = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.check),
      label: 'Bevestigd',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
      label: 'Afwachting',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.circle_notifications_outlined),
      label: 'Meldingen',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
      label: 'Profiel',
    ),
  ];

  final EmployeeButtons = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.circle_notifications_outlined),
      label: 'Meldingen',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
      label: 'Profielen',
    ),
  ];

  showScreens() {
    if(widget.rol == "Docent") {
      TeacherScreens[currentIndex];
    } else if(widget.rol == "Medewerker") {
      EmployeeScreens[currentIndex];
    } else {
      Center(child: Text("Error showing screens"));
    }
  }

  showButtons() {
    if(widget.rol == "Docent") {
      TeacherButtons;
    } else if(widget.rol == "Medewerker") {
      EmployeeButtons;
    } else {
      Center(child: Text("Error showing buttons"));;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      //body: Center(child: Text(widget.rol)),
      //body: EmployeeScreens[currentIndex],
      body: showScreens(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: mainColor,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        items: showButtons(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the return statement in the showButtons() and showScreens() methods.

This would be the correct way:

```
showScreens() {
    if(widget.rol == "Docent") {
      return TeacherScreens[currentIndex];
    } else if(widget.rol == "Medewerker") {
      return EmployeeScreens[currentIndex];
    } else {
      return Center(child: Text("Error showing screens"));
    }
  }

  showButtons() {
    if(widget.rol == "Docent") {
      return TeacherButtons;
    } else if(widget.rol == "Medewerker") {
      return EmployeeButtons;
    } else {
      return TeacherButtons;
    }
  }
```